# Use variable names of a the lists used in for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to utilize the variable names of the lists used in a for loop in python.

I have three lists:

```
a = ['red','blue','green']
b = ['dog','cat']
c = ['male','female']
```

Then I create a list of those previous lists:

```
group_list = [a,b,c]
```

I'm trying to iterate through the group list and print each variable name attached with a base string.

```
base_string='list_item'

for i in group_list:
     print(f'{base_string}_{i}')
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
list_item_['red','blue','green']
list_item_['dog','cat']
list_item_['male','female']
```

My desired result is:

```
list_item_a
list_item_b
list_item_c
```

Comment: use dictionary not list i guess to save name or save the name and values in pair in a list

Comment: Your data aren't structured properly to do this. A `dict` for `group_list` is the most obvious solution.

Comment: Variables are for *source code*, they are for the *programmer reading your code*. If you need to associate a *string* with some other object, then you should make that association explicit by using an appropriate data structure, as noted above, a `dict` here would be a natural choice

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , working fine

```
a = ['red','blue','green']
b = ['dog','cat']
c = ['male','female']
group_list = [a,b,c]
group_index =['a','b','c']

res = dict(zip(group_index, group_list))

base_string='list_item'

for i in res:

    print(f'{base_string}_{i}')
```

output:

```
list_item_a
list_item_b
list_item_c
```